# Why I can not load obfuscated assemblies dynamically?

Tags: c#

I'm using following code to load my assemblies dynamically:

```
FileStream io = new FileStream("AssemblyName.dll", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
if (io == null) return null;
BinaryReader binaryReader = new BinaryReader(io);
Assembly assembly = Assembly.Load(binaryReader.ReadBytes((int)io.Length));

return assembly;
```

But when my assembly ("AssemblyName.dll") is obfuscated, the methods of this assembly doesn't work right! I've seen some questions about this problem but their issues was different. I thought obfuscation doesn't change the execution logic.

I don't use reflection to get types of this assembly even, and I just load it in AssemblyResolve event when it is required.

**Edit:** *[Was resolved]* I just had a problem with a specific assembly, and I can load dynamically other obfuscated assemblies. I don't know what was the problem yet!

Comment: Can you describe "doesn't work right"?

Comment: Being unable to use reflection is one of the major reasons why people use obfuscation.

Comment: you can use as long as it remain an assembly, and there are public metohds to be called. usually all private method are obfuctated till their signatures, public methods are exception and can be called via reflection. also some obfuscator are also able to compile/bind/pack the assembly to a native executable which may fail in every aspect of reflection.

Comment: @nvoigt: For example they return null.

Comment: @Euphoric: Yes, You are right :) But how .Net framework load them?

Comment: @Euphoric: Also I thought obfuscation doesn't change the execution of an assembly.

Comment: @AliSepehri.Kh Obfuscator just changes the member names, then compiles it(emitting the IL with new unreadable member names). So it produces a valid IL which CLR is happy to execute.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: But when I load it manually, it doesn't work right, Why?

Comment: If _"doesn't work right"_ means _"For example they return null"_, then the problem is in your code, not the obfuscation.

Comment: @AliSepehri.Kh What doesn't work? Post the code which doesn't work. As CodeCaster says problem is with your code only.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: When I replace my obfuscated assembly with unobfuscated assembly, it works correctly. I debugged my code and I'm sure.

Comment: You still doesn't answered the question **What doesn't work?** Be specific.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: I thought my problem is because of obfuscation, but I found out this is very specific problem with my obfuscated assembly. How can I edit my question to be useful? Removing this question is the best way?

Comment: You can't delete a question with upvoted answer. Even if you edit the question I'm not sure how that will bring attraction. If problem is different you're better off asking a new question. Make sure you add all the required information to answer the question.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: No, my problem has been resolved, but I don't want to get negatives for my question, what can I do?!

Answer (score 2):

The methods work right, it is just that they have different names. Without knowing the exact configuration of your obfuscator it is impossible to tell what is obfuscated.

I would guess that the obfuscator leaves the public methods on public classes intact, whilst obfuscating almost everything else.

Obfuscation is usually done by giving the static and instance members new "human-unreadable" names, ie *finding a method through its unobfuscated name is nigh impossible*. You have to know the obfuscated name to find it, or it has to have a precise enough argument list so you can find it (which of course is hard if the arguments have obfuscated types...)

> While when .Net framework load obfuscated assemblies itself they work right. Does .Net framework use different code to load assemblies?

That is due to the fact that the public methods are not obfuscated, since that would kinda void the whole idea of assemblies.

My guess is that you are trying to do something which the author the assembly does not wish to be done, so you are on your own mate :)

Comment: No, the assemblies are my own and I want to protect my assemblies. I've encrypted them and in loading software they are decrypted and loaded. But I have problem with obfuscated assemblies. Also I am just using public methods!

Comment: Are you the one obfuscating them? How do you obfuscate them? Have you tried opening the assembly with a decompiler? (If you don't have one, try http://www.telerik.com/download/justdecompile (I do not work with Telerik or am in any way related to them, I just like their decompiler :)))

Comment: :) I wrapped my C# assemblies with an unmanaged c++ code. That is very reliable ;)

Comment: You cannot use reflection on unmanaged code, you know that right?

Comment: I'm just running a managed C# code from a C++ unmanaged code.